# jQuery text() and html() method not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

After some calculation I am trying to display the results in a table. I tried using .text() and .html() method but none of them working fine on Chrome (FF is perfectly fine).

1) .html() - Doesn't display anything on Chrome
2) .text() - Returns false string

Here is my JS function.

```
populateHomeGrid: function(categories, day) {

        var eventsForTimer = [];

        $.each(categories, function(index, value) {

            // categoryId -> {raceNumber : event, ...}
            var categoryName = value.name, categoryId = value.categoryId,
                mapOfEvents = [], maxNumberOfEvents = 0;

            // subcategories
            $.each(value.categories, function(index, category) {

                var mapOfOneCategory = {}, mapSize = 0;
                $.each(category.events, function(index, event) {
                    var raceNumber = event.raceNumber;
                    mapOfOneCategory[raceNumber] = event;
                    mapSize++;
                });
                if (mapSize > maxNumberOfEvents) maxNumberOfEvents = mapSize;
                mapOfEvents.push(mapOfOneCategory);
            })

            maxNumberOfEvents = maxNumberOfEvents;

            // drawing main category
            var tableId = "home_grid_" + day + "_" + categoryId,
                table = $('<table id="' + tableId + '" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" class="racing_tables" />')
                    .appendTo($('#' + day))

            var tr = $('<tr class="gray"/>')
                .appendTo(table)
                .append($('<td valign="middle" width="20%"/>')
                    .append($('<h2/>').html(categoryName)))

            for (var i = 1; i <= maxNumberOfEvents; i ++) {
                tr.append($('<td valign="middle" />')
                    .append($('<p/>').html(i)))
            }

            // drawing sub categories
            $.each(mapOfEvents, function(index, event) {

                // Drawing row
                var firstRow = true, categoryTr;

                for (var i = 1; i <= maxNumberOfEvents; i++) {

                    if (firstRow) {
                        categoryTr = $('<tr class="white"/>').appendTo(table)
                        var categoryHolder = $('<td/>').appendTo(categoryTr),
                            categoryName = $('<p/>').appendTo(categoryHolder)
                        firstRow = false;
                    }

                    if (typeof event[i] != 'undefined') {

                        categoryName.html(event[i].categoryName);
                        var categoryId = event[i].categoryId;

                        (function(i) {
                            var a = $('<a/>')
                                .click(function() {racingNavigation.showLocationAndRaceNumber(categoryId, i)})
                                .data('event', event[i])
                                .appendTo($('<td />')
                                    .appendTo(categoryTr))

                            if (racingNavigation.updateHomeCellInfo(a)) eventsForTimer.push(a);
                        })(i)
                    }
                    else {
                        categoryTr.append($('<td />'))
                    }
                }
            })
        });

        // Setting the counter to update the closing events
        var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
            $.each(eventsForTimer, function (index, value) {
                if (racingNavigation.updateHomeCellInfo(value) == null) {
                    window.clearInterval(intervalId);
                }
            })
        }, 5000);
        intervalIdsForUpdatingHomeGrid.push(intervalId);
    },
```

Function call to racingNavigation.updateHomeCellInfo

```
updateHomeCellInfo: function(a) {
        var info = '', redClass = false,
            event = $(a).data('event');

        // Killing the interval
        if (typeof event == 'undefined') return null;

        var timeUtc = event.timeUtc,
            status = event.status,
            neededForTimer = false;

        if (status == 'expired' || status == 'telephone') info = closed;
        else if (date.hourDifference(timeUtc) < 1 && date.minDifference(timeUtc) < 1  && date.secDifference(timeUtc) < 2 && (status == 'live' || status == 'run' )) info = closed;
        else if (event.result != null) {
            var position = 1;
            $.each(event.result.winPlaceResults, function() {
                var finishingPosition = this.finishingPosition,
                    selectionNumber = this.selectionNumber;
                if (parseInt(finishingPosition) == position) {
                    info += selectionNumber.toString();
                    position++;
                }
                if (position != 4) info += ', ';
                if (position == 4) return false;
            })
        }
        else {
            neededForTimer = true;
            if (date.hourDifference(timeUtc) > 0) {
                info = date.formatTime(new Date(timeUtc));
            }
            else {
                info = date.minDifference(timeUtc);
                if (info <= 5) redClass = true;
                info = date.minDifference(timeUtc) + ' ' + min;
            }
        }

        if (redClass) $(a).parent().addClass('red')
        else $(a).parent().removeClass('red');
        $(a).html(info);

        return neededForTimer;
    },
```

At the end of my second function I am displaying the result `$(a).html(info);`
where as info contains different element based on the calculations.
Default info is set to CLOSED which is defined in another file as var closed = "CLOSED".
I am expecting the table should display string CLOSED when all the different conditions are invalid.
 Both `.text()` and `.html()` method works fine on FF but not on Chrome as explained in the beginning.

Comment: could you create a fiddle as my work blocks betting sites

Comment: @Pete It would be really challenging for me to recreate the same scenario in Fiddle for my problem. I would appreciate If you happen to have a look after you work.

Comment: what happens if you use `a.html` rather than `$(a)` as you are passing through a jquery object so no need to wrap it again

Comment: @Pete No difference. Result is the same. Output is not displayed on Chrome.

Comment: I don't quite understand when closed is defined as var closed = "CLOSED" and in my function when I am assigning info = closed when the time for race is passed. It should display the text in anchor tag as CLOSED. If I use .text(info) instead of .html(info). The output is "FALSE"...but the var is already defined.

Comment: are you sure you are not overwriting closed somewhere as it looks to be a global var and should work: http://jsfiddle.net/hv8Yh/3/

Comment: @Pete Yes I am not overwriting the var and it is a global var defined in the the translation file. Infact all my global var which I am using in the site is defined in a separate file. Lets say even if I am overwriting the var closed why it is only working on FF?

Comment: I suppose you are using the function inside `(function ($) {} (jQuery));` The function is accessing the DOM element even before it is created. Try using the function in `ready` function.

Comment: Link full jQuery source (instead of minified script). Use Chrome's Tools->Developer Tools + breakpoint + watches + F11 (step inside) - to find out exactly what is in your variables. Without jsFiddle no better answer comes to my mind. You can do the same in FireFox and compare where is the difference